# Logger doesn't print debug messages after setting handler and log level

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have the following minimalist example of a `logging` test based on the [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-a-context-manager-for-selective-logging):

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('test')
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - '
                              '%(message)s')

ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)


print(logger.handlers)
logger.debug('hello world')
```

The above produces the following output:

```
$ python test_log.py
[<StreamHandler <stderr> (DEBUG)>]
```

As I've defined a handler and set the log level to debug, I was expecting the `hello world` log message to show up in the sample above.

Comment: Because your logger (not the handler) has level `NOTSET` in your example code, which means it will propagate the event to its only ancestor, the root logger, which does not have a handler to actually output something. As much as I dislike referencing my own answers; [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53477132/4134674) the long version of an answer. The short version would be: Add `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` to your code before you start using the logger.

Answer (score 1):

If a logger's level isn't explicitly set, the system looks up the level of ancestor loggers until it gets to a logger whose level is explicitly set. In this case, it's the root logger which is the parent of the logger named 'test'. Setting the level of either this logger or the root logger to DEBUG will result in the log message being output. See [this part](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) of the documentation for the event information flow in Python logging.

Answer (score 1):

So if we call `logger.debug('hello world')` we are generating a `DEBUG` event. However the logger acts as first filter before passing the event to the handlers. So if the logger level is at higher severity (like `INFO`) it will filter the event and the handler won't receive it, even if the event was matching the handler's level (`DEBUG`).

So the logger's level should be as low as the lowest level of its handlers. If you don't want the rest of the handlers to log `DEBUG` messages you would need to explicitly set their level higher, instead of leaving it unset and therefor inherited from the logger.